# Hardwired ethernet connection not coming up on Ubuntu 12.0.4

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, ethernet

I have a Toshiba Satellite P870 laptop in which the wireless connection is working but the eth0 is not showing up on networking. It does however show up in lspci:

Notice the second to last entry:    Qualcomm Atheros AR8162 Fast Ethernet

```
steve@mithril:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8162 Fast Ethernet (rev 10)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 2230 (rev c4)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

But the eth0 is not showing up

```
steve@mithril:~$ ifconfig -a
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:26500 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:26500 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:2380423 (2.3 MB)  TX bytes:2380423 (2.3 MB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 60:36:dd:9c:24:35  
          inet addr:10.0.0.31  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2601:9:7680:6bd:35da:dd37:2c59:f693/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: 2601:9:7680:6bd:6236:ddff:fe9c:2435/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::6236:ddff:fe9c:2435/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:437201 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:200898 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:560417483 (560.4 MB)  TX bytes:154418423 (154.4 MB)
```

Here is the /etc/network/interfaces file

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Here is **lshw -C network** :

```
steve@mithril:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: AR8162 Fast Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 10
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:c8600000-c863ffff ioport:2000(size=128)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Wireless-N 2230
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: c4
       serial: 60:36:dd:9c:24:35
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.2.0-65-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 ip=10.0.0.31 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:43 memory:c8500000-c8501fff
```

*UPDATE*  From attempting the fix from @guyfleeman

```
steve@mithril:/shared/compat-drivers-2013-03-04-u$ ./scripts/driver-select alx
Processing new driver-select request...
steve@mithril:/shared/compat-drivers-2013-03-04-u$ make
./scripts/gen-compat-autoconf.sh /shared/compat-drivers-2013-03-04-u/.config /shared/compat-drivers-2013-03-04-u/config.mk > include/linux/compat_autoconf.h
make -C /lib/modules/3.2.0-65-generic/build M=/shared/compat-drivers-2013-03-04-u modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-65-generic'
  CC [M]  /shared/compat-drivers-2013-03-04-u/compat/main.o
In file included from /shared/compat-drivers-2013-03-04-u/include/linux/compat-2.6.h:67:0,
                 from <command-line>:0:
/shared/compat-drivers-2013-03-04-u/include/linux/compat-3.4.h:43:21: error: redefinition of ‘kmalloc_array’
include/linux/slab.h:243:21: note: previous definition of ‘kmalloc_array’ was here
In file included from /shared/compat-drivers-2013-03-04-u/include/linux/compat-2.6.h:71:0,
                 from <command-line>:0:
/shared/compat-drivers-2013-03-04-u/include/linux/compat-3.8.h:49:32: error: redefinition of ‘kref_get_unless_zero’
include/linux/kref.h:47:32: note: previous definition of ‘kref_get_unless_zero’ was here
make[3]: *** [/shared/compat-drivers-2013-03-04-u/compat/main.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [/shared/compat-drivers-2013-03-04-u/compat] Error 2
make[1]: *** [_module_/shared/compat-drivers-2013-03-04-u] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-65-generic'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

Comment: see if any of the suggestions here work for you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/205582/how-do-i-get-an-atheros-ar8162-working

Comment: @FrankThomas  I did see that before, and had tried several of them. But after your comment I looked again. The last one about LTS looks interesting, i will try it and report back

Comment: The LTS suggestion actually did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Debian net_device header was changed in kernel version 3.8 and since some drivers have been experiencing issues. I ran into the issue with an ethernet card from the same family on Ubuntu 14.04 and these commands worked for me:

```
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2013/03/04/compat-drivers-2013-03-04-u.tar.bz2
./scripts/driver-select alx
make
sudo make install
reboot
```

The full forum can be found [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2139394).

Alternatively, many new atheros drivers are in this package. Go back to wireless and try running this command:

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Comment: Hi, I tried both above. The first one did not compile: see update my OP. Second one did not have any effect.  Thanks for the suggestions in any case.

Comment: This answer did not actually answer the question but was at least helpful, so i will accept.